# BrowserStack- Is it possible to automate test `

Tags: automation, automated-tests, browser-automation, browserstack

Guys am new to browserstack.

All i have is a valid credentials to login and i am unsure about running /automate the testcases in browserstack.

All i tried is running / manually pasting mu url in all devices and testing . But is there any way to automate this ?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated since it will resolve my roadblock ahead

Answer (score 0):

Everything supported by Selenium and Appium is supported on BrowserStack Automate and App Automate Product respectively. If you are able to execute test on your local device or local machine you will be able to execute the same on BrowserStack. It is very simple they also provide a document with the sample code in many different language binding which you can refer to. I am attaching the documentation which you can refer to below. If you want to execute a test on Mobile App you can refer to the documentation on App Automate and if you want to execute a test on a desktop machine or mobile browser refer to Automate documentation.

- [App Automate](https://www.browserstack.com/docs?product=app-automate)
- [Automate](https://www.browserstack.com/docs?product=automate)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Everything is documented on browser stack website from `setup` to `execution`. [Here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-cloud) you can find all details set up browser automation using `selenium` on browser stack. Please see below how you can set up webdriver remote instance  with your browser stack `credentials`

```
final String USERNAME = "";
final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "";
final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";

try
{
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("browser",browser);
caps.setCapability("browser_version",browser_version);
caps.setCapability("os",os);
caps.setCapability("os_version",os_version);
caps.setCapability("resolution",resolution);
caps.setCapability("project","Project-1");
caps.setCapability("build","1.0");
caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug","true");
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL),caps);
}
catch(MalformedURLException e)
{
e.getMessage();
}
```